# Can you finish the game siding with Caesar as a woman?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

As is fairly well-documented, Caesar's Legion is extremely sexist -- women do not serve his armies, are subservient to men in all ways, etc.

So my question is, if you are playing New Vegas as a woman, are you able to side with Caesar throughout the game and for the endgame? Does that modify any of the interactions with the Legion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes.**

You will be talked down to, insulted, barred from fighting in the arena, and may be locked out of the occasional unmarked quest, but it is entirely possible to side with the Legion with a Female character.

Why you'd *want to* on the other hand...